Advice on updating century-old children's story that has phonetically-spelled black dialogue
First, I think this question needs some background, but if you want to skip that, please skip down to "HERE'S MY QUESTION".
Most of classic American children's author Thornton W. Burgess's books were drawn from his daily newspaper syndicated column which he wrote for 48 years, 1912–1960. But many great narratives from his newspaper column were never republished as books. He is best known today for some of his earliest material.
I have been working on bringing some of these old narratives into book form. But I'm concerned about the dialogue of three main characters in his universe who are said to be from "Down South" and pretty clearly are coded as black by how they speak.
Some might leap to the conclusion that anything like this should be dustbinned on principle. But Burgess was ahead of his time on race (gender too), and I don't think his work deserves that.
The story I'm working on now was written in 1913. In 1913, most of Burgess's young readers would have been learning some level of racism from their elders. But Burgess subversively shows his black-coded characters fitting right in with all the others — accepted by them, friends with them, equally in conflict when the plot puts them there, no hint of different treatment. Given Burgess's massive popularity in the 1910s and 1920s, this surely must have influenced some of his many millions of young readers in the direction of racial acceptance and equality. I think the overwhelming likelihood is that Burgess accelerated the nation's progress toward racial equality, even if only modestly. And he must have done this on purpose.
In 1913, Joel Chandler Harris's 1881 book Uncle Remus: His Songs and His Sayings was still hugely popular, and it was still considered respectful to write black dialogue phonetically. That has long since changed dramatically of course; today it's understood to be offensive to write black dialogue phonetically.
Some old racist Hardy Boys books have been updated to modern standards, and I think it makes sense to do the same for Burgess. I'd like to update the dialogue in them.
HERE'S MY QUESTION:
What's the best way to update that dialogue? Four different ways occur to me:

Normalize the spelling, but preserve word choices. I like how this preserves and respects the character.
Same as (1) but also normalize subject-verb agreement. For example, change "I needs" to "I need" and "He need" to "He needs". I'm really not sure whether this is necessary vs. too intrusive.
Replace the "Perfective Done". For example, changing "I done been driven from" to "I've been driven from" and changing "you done have the same trouble" to "you've had the same trouble". Again I'm not clear on whether this is necessary vs. too intrusive.
Erase all racial encoding; make the characters from "Down South" talk like all the others. I think this would be offensive in its own way, effectively erasing Burgess's efforts to show blacks and whites in equality and friendship. Since these characters are animals, they are not otherwise coded as black or white.

Here's an example:

Ah done been driven from the Old Orchard by all mah ol’ friends and Ah reckons yo’ done have the same trouble. Don’t yo’ think we better put our haids together and find out what it all means?

(FWIW both of these characters are birds.)
#1 would look like this:

I done been driven from the Old Orchard by all my old friends and I reckons you done have the same trouble. Don’t you think we better put our heads together and find out what it all means?

#2 would look like this, changing reckons for subject–verb agreement:

I done been driven from the Old Orchard by all my old friends and I reckon you done have the same trouble. Don’t you think we better put our heads together and find out what it all means?

#3 would look like this, removing the Perfective Done:

I've been driven from the Old Orchard by all my old friends and I reckon you've had the same trouble. Don’t you think we better put our heads together and find out what it all means?

#4 is more flexible but might look something like this:

I've been driven from the Old Orchard by all my old friends and I believe you've had the same problem. Don’t you think we should put our heads together and find out what it all means?

What are your thoughts? Which of these is best to put in front of today's young children?

https://www.reddit.com/r/writing/comments/14gs9j8/writing_out_southern_accents/ ... #1 probably. But keep words like ain’t, gonna, y’all, etc. — words that are in the dictionary...

Have you looked at modern editions of books like Huckleberry Finn?

And as a preemptive warning to the commentariat: please avoid using this comments section to start an extremely  pointless and unproductive dispute about "political correctness."

I'm voting to close this question as opinion-based. Greg, as Barmar has suggested, look at the editorial practice and discussions surrounding republications of older American texts with black characters and form your own opinion. There is no single correct way how to do this. From a literary-historical standpoint preserving the original text is desirable, maybe with the addition of a critical foreword that explains the social situation and writerly practice of that time to present day readers; from a political perspective, rewriting the text to conform to todays moral standards is necessary.

Why in the heck would you change I needs to I need? Frankly, I'd leave it as is or not do it at all. It's like historical erasure. The Hardy boys are a different kettle of fish altogether. Put in a glossary.

after researching 'perfective done' I think #1 is best, but I have nothing official to back up my opinion.

I'm not an expert on this, but you say the characters are from "Down South" and provide an example. Is there any particular reason to assume that the accents are particularly black and not just generally Southern? See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Older_Southern_American_English and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English, which detail many of the features that stand out in the quote. If it's more geographic than racial, does that change your strategy?

The dialogue as is preserves the regional accent and is the same whether uttered by black, white or purple if living in that region.
"Correcting" the spelling might make the reader wonder if the characters are from Minnesota. Several of the Southern States have very distinctive accents and drawls. The Ah instead of I reflects that.
I am writing a work that incorporates black characters and I have a consultant who advises me on how those character will express themselves. I have a teenager who, I am assured, would not say need but needs. She would not say "I need to go." but "I needs to go.'
I have other black characters who have better grammar (that character's mother is a copy editor for a newspaper and dismayed by the way her daughter speaks). Each character must be true to themselves.
This desire to update the language to presumably make it less objectionable changes the characters.
They speak the way they do because of a variety of factors, upbringing, education, location and self confidence.
How a character speaks is crucial to who he is.
If you fear the stories will be considered racist simply because of how a person from that area can speak, you are seeking to sanitize it. If that is your concern, choose the first as it only gets rid of the regional accent and they will - except for an idiom or two) come from  Anywhere ville USA.
My question to you is, do the white characters also have an accent? If so, they are being encoded Southern. If not, then yes, carefully adjust it but keep the accent whenever and wherever possible.
The Ah instead of I would also be appropriate in Boston, with its pronounced drawl.
